# Llenar vectores con datos y realizar calculos en javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

**Se leen las 3 coordenadas de 3 vectores en el espacio(v1,v2,v3). Realice una app en javascript que muestre lo siguiente:

La magnitud de cada vector

El producto puento de v2 por V1

La suma de v1 + v2

La diferencia de v3-v1

La distancia entre v2 y v1**

Esto tengo que realizarlo en javascript y he intentado lo siguiente:

```
<script>
var valuesVector = [];

function Vector(i,j,k){
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.k = k;
}

function obtenerValores(){
    var i = document.getElementById('i-1').value;
    var j = document.getElementById('j-1').value;
    var k = document.getElementById('k-1').value;

    return i;
    return j;
    return k;
}
function CreaVector(){
    var vector = new Vector(obtenerValores());
    valuesVector.push(vector);
    mostrarCalculo();
} 
function mostrarCalculo(){
    var result = "";
    for(var i=0; i<valuesVector.lenght; i++){
        result+= 'i:' +  valuesVector[i].i + 
                'j:'+ valuesVector[i].j + 
                'k:'+ valuesVector[i].k + '\n';
    }
    document.getElementById('resul').innerText = result;
}
</script>

    <h4>VECTOR V1</h4>
    <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="i-1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="j-1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="k-1">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="obtenerValores(); 
    CreaVector();" type="button">Calcular</button>
    </form>
    <h4 id="resul"></h4>
```

Esto es lo que he intentado sin obtener ningun resultado, por ahora quiero mostrar los datos que he introducido en los input, pero no me muestra nada. Y tambien quisiera saber que como son 3 vectores V1 V2 Y V3 y cada uno tiene que tener 3 datos dentro de el, tendria que hacer una funcion distinta para obtener y calcular los datos para cada uno de los vectores? Necesito ayuda con esto, no se mucho de javascript y ando muy perdido

Answer (score 0):

el codigo de la función es incorrecto

```
    function obtenerValores(){
         var i = document.getElementById('i-1').value;
         var j = document.getElementById('j-1').value;
         var k = document.getElementById('k-1').value;

        return i;
        return j;
        return k;
```

}

Cuando haces eso solamente estas devolviendo el valor de 'i-1' ya que el primer return corta a los demas. Deberias devolver en este punto un vector con los tres valores y comenzar a trabajar desde ahi. Desde el html podes llamar directamente a CrearVector, ya que de ahi tambien estas utilizando obtenervalores.

Este codigo funciona ok (solo suma los valores de los 3 input a modo de ejemplo para orientarte), deje la funcion Vector, pero yo no la uso.

```
          <html>

          <script>

             var valuesVector = [];

             function Vector(i,j,k){
                      this.i = i;
                      this.j = j;
                      this.k = k;
              }

             function obtenerValores(){
                   var i = document.getElementById('i-1').value;
                   var j = document.getElementById('j-1').value;
                   var k = document.getElementById('k-1').value;

                 return [i,j,k];
                    }
              function CreaVector(){

                    valuesVector = obtenerValores(); 
                    var resultado=0;
                    for(var index=0;index<valuesVector.length;index++)
                     {

                         resultado=resultado+Number(valuesVector[index]);

                     }
                    document.getElementById('resul').innerText = resultado;

                  } 


         </script>


                  <body>
                    <h4>VECTOR V1</h4>                          
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="i-1">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="j-1">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="k-1">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                      onclick="CreaVector();">Calcular</button>   

                   <h4 id="resul"></h4>
                   </body>

                   </html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu ejemplo mostrarcalculo no funciona porque pusiste lenght cuando es length

```
      function mostrarCalculo(){
               var result = "";
              for(var i=0; i<valuesVector.lenght; i++){
                     result+= 'i:' +  valuesVector[i].i + 
                     'j:'+ valuesVector[i].j + 
                     'k:'+ valuesVector[i].k + '\n';
                     }
                 document.getElementById('resul').innerText = result;
                }
```

Espero sea de tu utilidad.

Saludos.